# Determining the total illumination of a polygon

Tags: graphics3d, simulation, modeling

> Is it possible to determine the total illumination of a particular polygon with the given light sources?

I truly acknowledge that *Mathematica* is not supposed to do this modeling, but it is what is at fingertips for the time being and, according to the [Documentation Center](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LightingAndSurfaceProperties.html), *Mathematica* somehow does it when rendering a 3D object:

> "Directional lighting" simulates a uniform field of light pointing in the given direction. The Wolfram Language adds together the light from all of these sources in determining the total illumination of a particular polygon.

The only thing I want is to take out that brightness number from processing of graphics and now I wonder does anybody know how to accomplish that?

Comment: What is the definition for "total illumination" and "brightness number" of a surface? Or do you want to compute the illumination of each point on the polygon separately?

Comment: @Pickett In Matematica, as I see, all points on some polygon have the same brightness. Try PolyhedronData["Tetrahedron"] as an example.

Comment: You are right, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: The rendering happens when the front end displays the graphics, so I don't think there is any way to obtain the illumination from the kernel. You could `Rasterize` the graphics and read a pixel value from the result but this will get tricky if there is more than one polygon.